# enumerating custom taxonomies?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, loop

I made this function that displays tags as an image grid

```
function execute_taxography() {
    $wpbtags = get_tags();
    $output.= '<div class="grid"><div class="taxography-grid"><ul>';
    foreach($wpbtags as $tag) {
        $output.= '<li class="item"><a href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'" style="background-image: url(\'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/tags/' . $tag->slug . '.png\')"><span class="count">'. $tag->count .'</span><span class="taxography-name">'. $tag->name . '</span></a></li>';
    }
    $output.= '</ul></div></div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Now I made a custom taxonomy named "book" and I want to display it in the same way as the tags but I'm stuck on the loop!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_tags` is just a wrapper around the more general taxonomy function `get_terms`. So you'll get the result you need with this:

```
function execute_taxography() {
    $wpbtags = get_terms( 'books' );
    $output.= '<div class="grid"><div class="taxography-grid"><ul>';
    foreach($wpbtags as $tag) {
        $output.= '<li class="item"><a href="'. get_term_link($tag->term_id, 'books' ) .'" style="background-image: url(\'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/tags/' . $tag->slug . '.png\')"><span class="count">'. $tag->count .'</span><span class="taxography-name">'. $tag->name . '</span></a></li>';
    }
    $output.= '</ul></div></div>';
    return $output;
}
```

I've also replaced function `get_tag_link` with `get_term_link`.

Read about `get_terms` at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms. Read about 'get_term_link` at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link

Comment: No worries! Also, you don't need to use `get_tags()` at all. `get_tags()` is basically the same as `get_terms( 'post_tag' )`. If you can input the taxonomy type as a variable you can find a way to implement both grids without duplicating code.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, much appreciated! BTW any ideas on adding pagination?

Comment: That's really a separate issue, try asking another question on SO.

Comment: This is extremely expensive to run